# Package runs in Visual but not in Job- Buffer Error- Sql server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, out-of-memory, buffer

My package runs perfectly from Visual Studio. I've also set up a Master Job package that essentially runs all the tasks for the ETL. When I try to run tasks from the deployed packages on the production SQL server, some pass and others fail. The Following issues occur:

> The Dataflow task failed to create a buffer to call the PrimeOutput for ADO NET source: error usually occurs to out-of-memory condition

The system reports 96 percent memory load. This is strange for two reasons, it runs fine on Visual 2012 on a server with 12 gigs and it is executing the same package on a server with 24 gigs.

Answer (score 2):

Have fewer packages run concurrently

Redesign the packages to avoid [asynchronous components](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx)

The production server might have 24GB of memory available but how much is allocated to SQL Server versus reserved for the OS? SSIS is going to run in the OS memory space

If any of your packages use 32 bit drivers, your entire process is going to be restricted to ~3GB of memory.

If you've bloated your string lengths to avoid the possibility of truncation errors, that's a quick way to see dtexec consume more memory than is required.

Comment: There are 21gig allocated to SQL, The sizes are set to a flexible +2 'max' because the ERP doesn't limit data sizes.

Comment: The question mostly relates to why the package runs perfectly in Visual and fails as a Job

Comment: 24 GB Server - 21 = 3GB for **all** OS activities. I'd wager the OS footprint alone is a gig so now, best case scenario, you're attempting to do all your SSIS work in 2 GB. Contrast that with your desktop experience where you have what, 8GB of available memory? Run a profile on the execution of the SSIS on your machine for all the same data as prod, how much memory does SSIS consume during execution? You're going to need a comparable amount free on the server or you need to re-architect the packages and/or master package to reduce memory needs

Comment: I changed the allocated memory and it still fails with 43 percent memory allocation